# Cómo puedo enviar un mensaje al detectarse un cambio en una columna en una spreadsheet de Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-simple-triggers

Hasta este momento tengo el siguiente código, pero solo se envía el mensaje si la celda es editada directamente por el usuario .. (y la celda se cambia por formula ligada a otras celdas)

```
function onEdit(event){


  var Colx = 24;  // Número de la Columna que contiene APLICAR POLITICA"


 var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();


   if (changedRange.getColumn() == Colx) {
    // Una celda de la Columna x ha sido editada

     var state = changedRange.getValue();

    // Detección de la politica

    switch (state) {

          case "APLICAR POLITICA":
        Browser.msgBox("Cuidado", "Por políticas se requiere depósito previo", Browser.Buttons.OK);
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de evaluar si la celda con la formula fue modificada evalúa si los parámetros que son entradas de usuario han sido modificados.

Lo anterior porque los activadores al editar (simple e instalable) y al cambiar (instalable) sólo son disparados cuando el usuario modifica la hoja de cálculo.

Referencia

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers